# in C, what is the maximum amount of identifiers you can have?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, limit, interpreter, identifier

what is the max amount of variables/identifiers you can have in C? Learning compiler theory and interpreter design, I've learned that identifiers and their values are stored via a symbol dictionary/hashmap.

Considering that hashmaps/dictionaries have a RAM limit, what would be the max amount of hashed identifiers possible in the C programming language?

Comment: I do not think there can be a general answer to that question, since this is implementation specific, and can also depend on the machine the compiler is running on.

Comment: Hard to say without more information. What platform (CPU/OS)? What compiler? Even then, depends on what the compiler writers went with.

Answer (score 10):

In general the number of identifiers is a *quality-of-implementation* issue. All compilers I know are only limited by available resources (memory).

There is, however, a (nearly useless) specification of minimum limits in the C Standard, C11, emphasis for identifiers by me:

> 5.2.4.1 Translation limits
>
> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one
>   program that contains at least one instance of every one of the
>   following limits:
>
> - 127 nesting levels of blocks
> - 63 nesting levels of conditional inclusion
> - 12 pointer, array, and function declarators (in any combinations) modifying an arithmetic, structure, union, or void type in a
>     declaration
> - 63 nesting levels of parenthesized declarators within a full declarator
> - 63 nesting levels of parenthesized expressions within a full expression
> - 63 significant initial characters in an internal identifier or a macro name (each universal character name or extended source character
>     is considered a single character)
> - 31 significant initial characters in an external identifier (each universal character name specifying a short identifier of 0000FFFF or
>     less is considered 6 characters, each universal character name
>     specifying a short identifier of 00010000 or more is considered 10
>     characters, and each extended source character is considered the same
>     number of characters as the corresponding universal character name, if
>     any)
> - **4095 external identifiers in one translation unit**
> - **511 identifiers with block scope declared in one block**
> - **4095 macro identifiers simultaneously defined in one preprocessing translation unit**
> - 127 parameters in one function definition
> - 127 arguments in one function call
> - 127 parameters in one macro definition
> - 127 arguments in one macro invocation
> - 4095 characters in a logical source line
> - 4095 characters in a string literal (after concatenation)
> - 65535 bytes in an object (in a hosted environment only)
> - 15 nesting levels for #included files
> - 1023 case labels for a switch statement (excluding those for any nested switch statements)
> - 1023 members in a single structure or union
> - 1023 enumeration constants in a single enumeration
> - 63 levels of nested structure or union definitions in a single struct-declaration-list

I consider it nearly useless due to the "at least one program" part. I think the intent is clear, but if your vendor sells you a compiler able to translate exactly one program testing these limits, then you won't get your money back :-)

Comment: "1024 members in a single struct or union" interesting limit

Comment: @Nergal Did you mean 1023?

Answer (score 4):

The standard doesn't specify a limit so it's down to the compiler or interpreter to make the choice.

You should also note that identifiers can be compiled out in the final binary.

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be any information in the C standard, but the C++ standard does mention some minimum recommendations which you probably could use as a guideline:

> **Annex B (informative)
>   Implementation quantities
>    [implimits]**
>
> (2.8)  — Identifiers with block scope declared in one block [1 024].